# Automatically download .txt file from emails using PHP

Tags: php, smtp, mms

I have a messaging service that uses phpmailer class to send emails to SMS using SMTP.  I'd like to send to MMS so it will keep all messages in one thread in a user's messaging app; however, when users reply to an MMS thread, the reply comes to my email as a .txt attachment.

I'd like to automatically download the text in the .txt file for every email that comes in and forward the email with the downloaded text to a zapier email parser.  If I forward incoming email without first pulling out the text in the .txt file, the zapier parser cannot parse out the information I want.  Is there a good mail class that can help me accomplish this?

Comment: I used flourish http://flourishlib.com/docs/fMailbox to to make a email client to handle attachments.

Comment: if your using a sms gateway they should have an api, and you can skip the getting a response in to your email